A problem of determining whether a power series belongs to $\mathbb{C}(u)$
I am reading a paper "Drinfeld coproduct, quantum fusion tensor category and applications"
and I have a probelm.
Here is the arxiv:Drinfeld coproduct, quantum fusion tensor category and applications.
On page $13$ of this paper, the author define a power series:
$$\mathcal{R} _s(u)=\sum_{t\geqslant 1}{u^{rt}}u^{k_3t}\lambda _{3}^{t}u^{tk_{2,+}}\lambda _{2,+}^{t}t^{s+k_3^\prime}$$
where  $r\in \mathbb{Z}$, $s\ge 0,k_3\ge 0,k_3^\prime\ge 0,k_{2,+}\ge 0, \lambda_{2,+},\lambda_{3}\in \mathbb{C}^*$.
Then the author says $\mathcal{R} _s(u)\in \mathbb{C}(u)$.
I think  $\mathbb{C}(u)$ denotes the set of rational polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$.
I think this is equivalent to $$\sum_{t\ge 1}u^t t^s\in \mathbb{C}(u)$$ for a fixed $s\ge 0$?
So how can I get $\mathcal{R} _s(u)=\dfrac{f(u)}{g(u)}$ where $f(u), g(u)\in \mathbb{C}[u]$?
Any help and references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I think it helps to get rid of all the over-elaborate notation. Surely the sum is just $\sum_{t\geqslant} t^{m} (\alpha u^{p})^{t}$ which I think must be a sum of derivatives of $\frac{1}{1-\alpha u^p}$. As you've stated the question I can't see that $p$  is integral, and if it's not I have my doubts about the truth of the assertion.

Thank you for your comment!  I ignorethat $s+k_3^\prime \in \mathbb{N}$.

Are $k_2, k_3, s$ all integral?

@ancient mathematician Yes, they are all integral and all $\ge 0$. I ignore it. So I think it  can be obtained by derivating + multiplying $u$ and repreating for finite steps.

Yes, I reckon $(u\frac{d}{du})^m$ will do it.
